# Loop and place multiple values in 1 single cells VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a following tables (Simplyfing)

```
City   Value
paris   1
London  2
Leeds   3
Hanoi   4
Newyork 5
```

I have this condition: `If value <= 3 Then` accepted and put into a single cell, like this : `Paris, London, Leeds`.

If I use loop with `MsgBox`, then I can easily show all but I don't know how to put all values into a single cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation in the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ResultsinSingleCell()

Dim ResultRng           As Range
Dim C                   As Range
Dim LastRow             As Long
Dim ResString           As String

With Worksheets("Sheet7") ' replace "Sheet7" with your sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- get last row in Column "A" (where the list of cities exist)

    Set ResultRng = .Range("C2") ' <-- set the range of the result

    ' loop through all values in column "B"
    For Each C In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Cells
        If C.Value <= 3 Then
            If ResString = "" Then  '<-- check if string is empty >> first match
                ResString = C.Offset(, -1).Value
            Else
                ResString = ResString & ", " & C.Offset(, -1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next C
End With
ResultRng.Value = ResString

End Sub
```

*Screen-shot after running the code with your sample-data*:

[image]